# MInimal KMS key permissions for cost and usage reports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-kms

I need to setup AWS cost and usage reports. For this I need to create an s3 bucket and a key using KMS. To give a brief about account structure in AWS - there are multiple accounts that I am using and all these accounts are linked to a central billing account.

For creating a KMS key, what permissions should I give so that I am able to view and download any files/ reports that are uploaded on S3 bucket solely being used for this purpose.